# type conversion from fixed and ufixed to string

Tags: solidity, type-casting

i have a contract and within the contract i have a function which takes two variables from the input from the user, one of them is integer and one of them is double (both are necessary to the operation). i could type cast from int to string, but i could not type cast from fixed and ufixed to string. does anyone know how to convert? the compiler of course does not allow explicit type conversion from fixed to string, Explicit type conversion not allowed from "ufixed128x18" to "string storage pointer"

```
function getAbonacci(uint yclose, ufixed128x18 dclose) public payable {
   if (provable_getPrice("URL") > address(this).balance) {
       emit LogNewProvableQuery("Provable query was NOT sent, please add some currency to cover for the query fee");
   } else {
       emit LogNewProvableQuery("Provable query was sent, standing by for the answer..");

       //s2 = yclose; uint256 conversion to string
       s2 = uint2str(yclose);
       
       //s3 = dclose;
       x1 = string(dclose);
       
       s4 = string(abi.encodePacked(s1, "yclose=" , s2 , "&dclose=" , s3));
       //http://abwservice.com/api/webapi/service/?Token=xxxx&yhigh=0&ylow=0 &yclose=0&dclose=1888
       provable_query("URL", string(s4));
   }
```

}

s1, s2, s3, s4 are all strings. and i tried nearly everything for s3

Comment: Please share the code. The conventional way of doing this is to implement everything with integers, and perform the actual division (integer-division) only when necessary: 1. When you return it to the offchain caller. 2. When you pass it to a function in another (not your) contract. 3. When your intermediate result might overflow if you apply any more multiplications or additions on it.

Comment: i added the code. plz see if you can help it

Comment: What is the expected range of `dclose` in your system?

Comment: And does the `abwservice` API even take non integer values as input for the this parameter?

Comment: expected range is 8 decimals after the floating point. i.e 1.12345678. i don't even know how to work with fixed and ufixed since 'Fixed point numbers are not fully supported by Solidity yet. They can be declared, but cannot be assigned to or from', is said by the dolidity docs 0.7.5